# PHP if statements unsure where I'm wrong

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to specify that my logo appears on some pages and not on others, the only pages I do not want it showing on are the homepage and /index.php. I have the big logo appearing and disappearing as I want it and so I presumed I could just do the opposite for the small logo but I must be doing something wrong. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$dunpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if ($dunpage != '/index.php' || $dunpage != '/') {?>      
<h1 class="small-logo">
<a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
<?php } 
?>
<?php
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if ($currentpage == '/' || $currentpage == '/index.php') {?>
<h1 class="logo";>
  <a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
<?php } 
?>
```

Comment: `$dunpage != '/index.php' || $dunpage != '/'` this condition **always** evaluates to `TRUE`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick replies. They were very helpful. Saved me a lot of time I'm sure :-)

Comment: @user1021330 Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are satisfied with an answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beneath its score.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a logical OR in your first condition, you should be using a logical AND:

```
$dunpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if ($dunpage != '/index.php' || $dunpage != '/') {?> 
// Should be
$dunpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if ($dunpage != '/index.php' && $dunpage != '/') {?>
```

Effectively, you were saying "act if the page is either not `index.php`, or not `/`." So in either of those cases, the opposite would be true. If it wasn't `index.php`, it could be `/`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if ($dunpage != '/index.php' && $dunpage != '/') {
```

for your small logo.

Answer (score 2):

You correctly negated the == operator, but not the || operator. You're saying that if dunpage is not /index.php OR dunpage is not /, do that, which basically means do that always. Change || to && for the small logo.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an else?

```
<?php
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; if ($currentpage == '/' || $currentpage == '/index.php') { ?>
<h1 class="logo";>
  <a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
<?php 
} else {
?>
<h1 class="small-logo">
  <a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
<?php 
}
?>
```

(You don't actually mention that it's either a large or a small logo that you want to display, but I have to assume that is the case here.)

Or you can use in_array() in this case.

```
<?php
$displayMainLogo = array('/', '/index.php');
if ( in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $displayMainLogo) ) { ?>
<h1 class="logo";>
  <a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
<?php 
} else {
?>
<h1 class="small-logo">
  <a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
<?php 
}
?>
```

If you understand how to do a ternary (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), then this is as terse as you can make it.

```
<h1 class="<?php echo (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $displayMainLogo)) ? 'logo' : 'small-logo' ?>";>
  <a href="/" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>"><span><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
</h1>
```